# BCP Date Formatting

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm converting a date to a string in a Stored Procedure, to send to a BCP. This works but the formatting in the CSV appears to open as `dd-mm-yyyy` despite using type 103 which should show dd/mm/yyyy' (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Code:

```
USE [Database]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spExcelIntoTableMainReport]
(
    @tableName sysname,
    @xModuleID varchar(Max) 
)
AS
BEGIN
---------------------------------------
DECLARE @FilePath varchar(150)
SELECT @FilePath = 'C:\Sites\Reposts\' 
--------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
---------------------------------------
DECLARE @tableCREATE NVARCHAR(2500)

SET @tableCREATE = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tableName + '
(
[ID] VARCHAR(200),
DateFrom  varchar(100),
DateTo  varchar(100)
 )'
EXEC (@tableCREATE)
---------------------------------------
SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @tableName  + '
(
ID,
DateFrom  ,
DateTo
)
VALUES
(
''ID'',
''Date From (DD/MM/YYYY)'' ,
''Date to (DD/MM/YYYY)''
)'
EXEC (@sql)

SET @sql = '
INSERT INTO ' + @tableName  + '
(
ID,
DateFrom  ,
DateTo
)

SELECT ID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(10),cast(ModuleDateStart as Date),103))),
LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(10),cast(ModuleDateComplete as Date),103) )),
FROM TBLRESULTS'

EXEC (@sql)

--------- Now we have a table create the CSV ----------
DECLARE @sql1 varchar(8000)
SELECT @sql1 = 'bcp DATABASE+ @tableName + ' out ' + @FilePath + ''+  @tableName + '.csv -c -t, -T -S '+ @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql1  

END
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly, and what is your exact question? I'm not seeing a clear problem description and neither do I see a question.

Comment: Amended question but I want dd/mm/yyyy not dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: I would almost guarantee that your BCP process is working correctly and that it is in fact Excel that is applying some sort of default format to your dates. Try editing the csv in Notepad++ for example and see what the values are

Comment: Just ran `DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000);SET @cmd='BCP "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103)" QUERYOUT "C:\temp\test_date.txt" -T -c -S'+ @@SERVERNAME;EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;`. The file contents: `05/12/2016`.